# how to clone objects javascript webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

```
    //bootstrap.js
    window.numToRubles = require('./custom/rubles');

    //in rubles.js
    (function() {
         var rubles = function(number, template) {
            ....
            return text;
         }

    globals.rubles = rubles;

    })();
```

It works correctly

```
    //in app.js
    numToRubles.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:true, dat:false});
```

But if I change some options in other call

```
    //in app.js
    numToRubles.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:true, dat:false});
    numToRubles.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:false, dat:true});
```

It will have an impact on the first value

I try to clone object in

```
    //bootstrap.js
    window.numToRubles  = require('./custom/rubles');
    window.numToRubles2 = window.numToRubles = jQuery.extend(true, {}, window.numToRubles);

    //in some.js
    numToRubles.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:true, dat:false});
    numToRubles2.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:false, dat:true});
```

But it not works. It has same behavior.

Now, I forced it to work like this:

```
    window.numToRubles  = require('./custom/rubles');
    window.numToRubles2 = require('./custom/rubles2');
```

But it is bad way.

How I can do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote rubles.js into class's style

```
//in rubles.js
(function() {

  //var somePar = [....];// and I transferred this property to the class
                        // I suppose that the manipulation of this array 
                        // led to a negative result before



    //add the constructor
     var Rubles = function(template) {

        var s = this;

        s.somePar = [....];

        s.getRes(n){
            ...
            return n;
        }

     }


globals.Rubles = Rubles;

})();
```

and when

```
  window.Rubles = require('./custom/rubles');

  window.numToRubles = new window.Rubles.Rubles({nominal:true, div:true, dat:false});
  window.numToString = new window.Rubles.Rubles({nominal:false, div:false, dat:true});

  res1 = numToRubles.getRes(n);
  res2 = numToString.getRes(n);
```

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
window.numToRubles  = require('./custom/rubles');
window.numToRubles2 = window.numToRubles.bind({}); 
//clones the function with '{}' acting as it's new 'this' parameter
```

Now

```
//in some.js
numToRubles.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:true, dat:false});
numToRubles2.rubles(val, {nominal:true, div:false, dat:true});
```

Comment: No, it is not work for me. 
window.numToRubles2 = window.numToRubles.bind({});  //window.numToRubles.bind is not a function.

if I set 
window.libRub = require('./custom/rubles');

window.numToRubles = window.libRub.rubles.bind({});
window.numToRubles2 = window.libRub.rubles.bind({});

the same affect